# Ayuda para solucionar error 1054 Unknown column '...' in 'field list' en mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Quisiera pedir su ayuda para solucionar el error:

> 1054 Unknown column '...' in 'field list'

La columna que me marca como desconocida Tiene el nombre Edad y la marca como desconocida a pesar de que si esta en la tabla y escrita tal cual.

Esta es la forma en que me marca el error:

```
   Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the 
database.<br/>
    ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'Edad' in 'field list'<br/>
    SQL Statement:<br/>
    INSERT INTO `ropa`.`ropavendida` (`claveRopExVendi`, `NumCliente_fk`, 
`NumEmpVendi`, `FormaPago`, `Cantidad`, `PrecioTotal`, `Dia`, `Mes`, `Año`, 
`Edad`) VALUES ('1', '1', '11', 'Efectivo', '15', '375', '11', 'Junio', '2018', 
'28')
```

Comment: la claveRopExVendi es autogenerable? si es ese caso no deberias insertarlo, solito lo hara

Comment: No, ninguno es autogenerable

Comment: dia mes año de que tipo son?

Comment: Dia y año son INT, Mes es un VARCHAR, pero antes de meterle la edad a la tabla me jalaba bien al meterle los datos

Comment: ¿Puedes ponernos la creacion de la tabla?

Comment: Yo te preguntaría: ¿por qué guardas `Dia, Mes, Año` en columnas separadas en vez de usar una única columna del tipo `DATETIME`?  ¿por qué guardas un campo calculado `Edad` ... ? ¿qué pasará cuando la edad **cambie** cada año? ¿Por qué no agregas otra tabla con las formas de pago?

Comment: Porque con datetime estaba marcando errores y la edad solo se requiere al momento de realizar la compra